# Sharepoint Online: How do I find out the external sharing configuration for my tenant through REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, rest

How do I know what the External sharing configuration is for my tenant? I need to know if there is any REST API that would give me this information?

The information shown here

http://www.sptechcon.com/news/getting-started-with-external-access-in-office-365

How can I get this info through an API call?